# PyQt making button clickable after 15 seconds

Tags: button, timer, pyqt4

I am working with PyQt4. After a user clicks a button (btnReload) the button get's locked and my app get's some values from a server in the background. Because I don't want the user to be able to spam this server the user should just be able to press the button every 15 seconds.

Code:

def btnReloadClicked(self):

```
    self.ui.btnReload.setEnabled(False)

    def timerforbutton():

        threading.Timer(15.0, timerforbutton).start()

        self.ui.btnReload.setEnabled(True)


    #how to stop after the def timerforbutton() is runced once?

    self.getTransactionData()
```

How can I stop the timerforbutton after it's executed once a time?
Here's what should happends:
User clicks button-> btn gets locked -> after 15 seconds button is unlocked.
I can't use sleep() because this would freeze the whole GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a timer and either a slot or directly a callable made by partial.

```
from functools import partial
self.ui.btnReload.setEnabled(False)
QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(15000, partial(self.ui.btnReload.setEnabled, True));
```